# Replace image with text on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap I want to replace image with text when max-height = 768x (on mobile).

Here's my snipped http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/XaB7r.

I've tried to add:

**content:'mytext';**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  nav.navbar.navbar-default.shrink {
    min-height: 35px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
  nav.shrink.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    padding-top: 2px;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
  nav.shrink.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand img {
    height: 40px;
**content:'mytext';**
  }
  nav.shrink.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    margin-top: 11px;
  }
```

Comment: I assume you mean "when max-width = 768px"... have a 2nd div/span for the text (.navbar-brand-text)..   toggle .navbar-brand and .navbar-brand-text...  also try not to use max-width    use min-width if possible   (edit:  this question has absolutely nothing to do with PHP)

Comment: Yes max-width=768px "php" sorry wrong tag!
I just want when it's on max-width=768px to remove logo but to add some text because logo not visible good.

Comment: I believe the `content` property can only be applied to pseudo elements. Try adding an `:after` pseudo element to your `.navbar-brand` element with that property. As a side note, using the `content` property to insert text is inadvisable from an accessibility standpoint, unless the text is purely decorative.